# use factory friend class to allocate new class, good practice?

Tags: c++, factory, friend

i have a complex class that i want to force the user to use std::unique_ptr for it, the way i see it the best way is to create a factory method that returns a std::unique_ptr and hide the ctor.

problem is, the more factory methods i add the dirtier the header and code starts to look.

so i thought maybe if i create a new ClassFactory class that has all the factory methods inside it, it would look cleaner and every time i want to add a new factory method i just edit the factory class and be done with it (leaving the original class clean).

for example:

```
class Widget
{
private:
    friend class WidgetFactory;

    Widget(){}
    Widget(const Widget& other) = delete;
    Widget& operator = (const Widget& other) = delete;

    std::string _msg;

public:
    void printMessage(){ std::cout << _msg << std::endl; }
};

class WidgetFactory
{
public:
    static std::unique_ptr<Widget> create(){ auto w = std::unique_ptr<Widget>(new Widget);
                                             w->_msg = "hello world!"; return w; }
};
```

and then the user:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    auto w = WidgetFactory::create();
    w->printMessage();
}
```

another way is to make the ctor explicit public with a private token so i can use std::make_shared/unique.

but i dont recall seeing this pattern before, so my question is, is this good practice? would you mind seeing code like this from your coworkers?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not define move-constructor and move-assignment operators for `Widget`? Then you could setup a unique_ptr with the rvalue.

Comment: thanks for the answer. im sorry, but i dont understand how that could help, where would i setup a unique_ptr with the rvalue? that means i would have to build all ctors (instead of the factory methods) and moves right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is not a good practice :

1. you will not be able to create such objects for unit testing - you would have to use the factory
2. using `std::unique_ptr` for everything reminds of the saying "when you have a new hammer, everything looks like a nail". It has a good use, but it doesn't solve all problems
3. the code with `auto` looks nice, but you can not use it to create member variables
4. for big (or at least medium) projects, using one factory for everything is going to become very cumbersome, and is going to defeat it's purpose

The factory pattern is good (and I personally like it), but I don't think that literally every object needs to be created using it.

Comment: thanks for the answer. never though about unit testing thats a good point. i know this class looks way to simple but the one im working on is a C wrapper with a lot of pointers and functions that work on those pointers. so i should just stick to constructors? but if i get to something like 10 different constructors, wont that make my code look just worse? also copy and move aren't always trivial and can be a pain to create, thats why i went for the std::unique_ptr

Comment: @sap You can still use the factory pattern with std::unique_ptr, just don't hide the constructors. And do not use one factory for all objects.

Comment: @sap typically, the factory would be used for runtime polymorphism, e.g. to create concrete classes with a common interface. Each concrete class would have a `create()` function, and the factory class would store a registry of function pointers of these createors. The registry can be probed at runtime to see which particular concrete class has to be assigned to a `std::unique_ptr<Base>`. The creator functions simply return a `std::make_unique<Derived>`. But you want the constructors public because clients that know which class to generate, should be able to do so without a `unique_ptr`.